# Fill null values using information from another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following example dataframe:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'planet':['Earth','Earth','Mars',np.nan,'Venus','Mars',np.nan,'Venus','Earth',np.nan],
               'group':['alpha','alpha','beta','gamma','delta','beta','delta','delta','gamma','beta']})
```

Every row is an individual's planet and group. It is given that the planet of a particular group is same for all individuals. So if alpha group is from Earth, all individuals in alpha group are from Earth. I want to use this information to fill the missing values in planet column.

What I did was create a dataframe with rows that are missing planet values:

```
df2 = df[pd.isna(df['planet'])]
```

and used the groups in df2 to slice the original dataframe, adding the condition that planet values are not null:

```
df3 = df[(~pd.isna(df['planet'])) & (df['group'].isin(df2['group']))]
df3 = df3.drop_duplicates()
```

Now how do I fill in the missing values in the original dataframe (df)? Is there a better method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if alpha group is from Earth, all individuals in alpha group are from
> Earth

This suggests that one way that you could use is to `groupby.transform` the `first` to fill in the missing values:

```
df['planet'] = df.groupby('group')['planet'].transform('first')
```

Output:

```
  planet  group
0  Earth  alpha
1  Earth  alpha
2   Mars   beta
3  Earth  gamma
4  Venus  delta
5   Mars   beta
6  Venus  delta
7  Venus  delta
8  Earth  gamma
9   Mars   beta
```